# How to create dictionary from post data?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a function that returns prints a dict list like
`{'a':['x1,x2,x3'], 'b':['x1,x2], 'c':['x3']}`

How can I initialize this into a dict on its own then be able to play with that "new" dict?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the post-data is a string, just use `eval` -

```
post_data = "{'a':['x1,x2,x3'], 'b':['x1,x2'], 'c':['x3']}"
new_dict = eval(post_data)
```

Alternatively, and possibly "safer", use `json.loads`, after fixing the quotes to double quotes -

```
import json

post_data = "{'a':['x1,x2,x3'], 'b':['x1,x2'], 'c':['x3']}"
new_dict = json.loads(post_data.replace("'", '"'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `eval` if possible. If there are no variables, use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> import ast
>>> inp="{'a':['x1,x2,x3'], 'b':['x1,x2'], 'c':['x3']}"
>>> d=ast.literal_eval(inp)
>>> d['a']
['x1,x2,x3']
```